# Display AWS CloudWatch query result based on logStream creation time

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

given the following AWS CloudWatch log query:

```
fields @logStream, @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like "- PerformanceTests"
| parse @message /PerformanceTests\/(?<testCase>\w+?):\s*(?<metric>\w+?):\s*(?<executionTime>\d+?)\s*ms/
| stats avg(executionTime) as ExecutionTime by @logStream, testCase, metric
| sort @logStream.creationTime asc
| limit 100
```

The query about would be used to detect performance changing in our tests.

The idea is that I want to group execution time mainly on the logStream, and each stream groups contains many bars based on the testcase and metrics.

The groups should be sorted by the creation time of the logStream, make a visualized barchart obvious for the developer to see, if any performance degradation happened.

The problem is that the sort seems doesn't really sort the bars during visualization

Can anybody help me? Thank you